# how to count that how many user rated a specific items in php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Well,i got so many same result in stackoverflow but that was not in php and mysqli.I am trying to count how many users who have rated to specific item.Like 10 users rated item_id 21.Actually i am able to show how many user rated specific items by using count in select * on web page but i also need to store them in my db.So,that i am able to suggest other ussers the most rated product.For this i need to store how many users who have rated to specific item.But i don't know.My code is in pdo.plz help me out.

In this code,i am able to show them in webpage using count but i want to store them in db too.i dont know where i should i put insert query.because in my code $output is used to just show output not for insertion..

```
<?php
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=final', 'root', '');
  $id=$_GET['id'];

$query = "SELECT p.*,COUNT(r.rating) as rating_num FROM search
 as p LEFT JOIN rating as r ON r.business_id = p.id WHERE p.id = $id"; 
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$output = '';
foreach($result as $row)
{
 $rating = count_rating($row['id'],$connect);
 $color = '';
$count='';
$output .= '
<h1 class="text-center  mt-1 mb-2 p-2" style="text-transform:capitalize;background-color:white;color:black;text-align:center;">Brand_Name:'. $row["brand"].'</h1>
';
$output .= '
<div class="columnhead" style="padding-left:140px;text-align:left;background-color:white;">
<p style="font-size:30px;"><b>Name:</b>'.$row["name"].'</p>
<p style="font-size:30px;"><b> Brand_name:</b>'.$row["brand"].'</p>
 <p style="font-size:30px;"><b>Code:</b>'.$row['code'].'</p>
<p style="font-size:30px;"><b>Color:</b>'.$row['color'].'</p>
<p style="font-size:30px;"><b>Size:</b>'.$row['size'].'</p>
<p style="font-size:30px;"><b>Price:</b>'.$row['price'].'</p>
';
for($count=1; $count<=5; $count++)
 {
  if($count <= $rating)
  {
   $color = 'color:#ffcc00;';
  }
  else
  {
   $color = 'color:#ccc;';
  }
  $output .= '
 <ul  class="inline-list  title="Average Rating - '.$rating.'" style="display:inline-block;list-style-type: none; padding: 0;"">
<li  title="'.$count.'" name="'.$row['name'].'" id="'.$row['id'].'-'.$count.'" data-index="'.$count.'"  data-business_id="'.$row['id'].'" data-rating="'.$rating.'" class="rating" style="cursor:pointer; '.$color.' font-size:16px;">&#9733;</li>
</ul>
'; 
}
  $output .= '
<p>('.$row["rating_num"].' users voted)</p>
';
 $output .= '
 <form method="post" action="mycart.php?action=add&id='.$row['id'].'">  
                <p style="font-size:30px;"><b>Quantity:</b></p><input type="text" name="quantity" class="button1" value="1" width="15px">
                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="'.$row['name'].'">
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="'.$row['price'].'"> 
<br/> 
  <input type="submit" class="a" name="add_to_cart" value="Add to Cart">
        </form>
</div>

';
}
echo $output;
 
function count_rating($business_id,$connect)
{
 $output = 0;
 $query = "SELECT AVG(rating) as rating FROM rating WHERE business_id = '".$business_id."'";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 $total_row = $statement->rowCount();
 if($total_row > 0)
 {
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
   $output = round($row["rating"]);
 }
 }
 return $output;
 
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't understand where is the difficult, when user press "rating button" you can use ajax to update/insert record.

Comment: yes my rating value is insert plus update too but i need to store how many users rated that item so that i can recommend my users the most rated items.I used ajax to insert and update but dont know how to pass Count(r.rating) to ajax.

Comment: I suppose, if you have for example table product (so each product will store here) just add one column call rating and add 1 all time user press button. 
So user click to button - ajax call to update page - value + 1 .
Simple no?

Comment: Listen,as i told you that in item description page(web page) it is shown that how many users rated it using count.I just simply asking that is there way to store count value on db

Comment: If you use that feature, it is assumed that you have previously entered the review record. when you enter the record you increase the value of the review by one